# Enumerate spacing changes discontinuously

Tags: spacing, enumerate, enumitem, vspace

I've got a problem with the spacing management in enumerate.
Here are the packages in my main .tex document:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}



 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={155mm,247mm},
 left=30mm,
 top=25mm,
 }

 \setlength\parindent{0pt}



\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
```

Everything is working fine with the spacing everytime I use enumerate or itemize, except here

```
   Wähle $l\in\{0,\dots,l_2-1\}$ fest und betrachte $\sigma_l$. Da $S_n$ (n,\epsilon)$-dicht ist, gibt es ein $m_l\in\mathbb{N}$,
   $z_0^l,\dots,z_{m_l}^l \in \text{Bild}(\sigma_l)$ und $x_0^l,\dots,x_{m_l}^l\in S_n$ so, dass:\vspace{-0.7em}\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
 \item für $i=0,\dots,m_l$ $z_i^l\in B^{d_n}_{\epsilon}(x_i^l)$ gilt und
 \item für $i=0,\dots,m_l-1$ das Teilsegment von $\sigma_l$ von $z_i$ nach $z_{i+1}$ in
$B^{d_n}_{\epsilon}(x_i^l)\cup B^{d_n}_{\epsilon}(x_{i+1}^l)$ enthalten ist.
\end{enumerate}
```

Without any specification, the space between items and before and after the list were extremely large. With [noitemsep] the space between items is reduced
[image: .]
For the other problem I tried to use \vspace, but it's not working. If I set it to -10 em, the first line of the list is over the text before.
[image: .]
When changing the value, the list just suddenly jumps again to a big distance.
I also tried to use paralist, but nothing has changed.
It seems that I can change only the inner distance or only the outer, but not both together.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

The problem is the presence of an indivisble object in the following page. So it is not directly related to enumerate.
\raggedbottom in the preambles or \newpage solve the problem.

Comment: Quite likely you have some big indivisible object on the next page.

Comment: Oh, yes, I think that's exactly the case: there is a minipage with an image inside.
What should I do?

Comment: Let that image float with a `figure` environment.

Comment: I did it, but nothing changed, so I tried to remove the image. The problem persists. After the image there is a long equation environment. Does that also count as a big indivisible object?

Comment: I just tried to force \newpage. This works. It's not an optimal solution, but I guess it can't be better.

Comment: please always post code as a complete document that shows the problem, not just fragments. Also unrelated, but I would avoid `\usepackage{commath}`

Comment: probably you want to add `\raggedbottom` to your preamble so that spaces are not stretched, but hard to be sure as you have posted no example

Comment: thanks a lot for the advice!